# How can I use TEXT JOIN with a For Loop in excel

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I have a large worksheet with hundreds of similar ID #'s where I randomly assign a color to the ID and individual Materials to help prevent mixing them up while quickly scanning and I want to combine all the materials from the ID rows into one formatted cell using

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,B2:B5)
```

but I'm missing something.

I can't figure out how to "say", as long as the ID is the same, append the Material to the TEXTJOIN Range.

(e.g. Cells C2, C6, C8, C12, C13, & C14 would have the formatted list of materials if I could figure this out)

```
Sub ColorID()
' Randomly assign color for each ID#
    Dim r As Integer, g As Integer, b As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    
   With ActiveSheet
        lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(5000, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    Dim i As Integer, x As Integer
'i is row counter (needs to start on 2 due to header rows

    i = 2
       
        r = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(128, 255)
        g = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(128, 255)
        b = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(128, 255)
        
'Set the For loop
    For i = 2 To lastRow - 1
    
    ' Color the Cells
        Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(r, g, b)
        Cells(i, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(r, g, b)
        
'*** **This is where I'm stuck** ***
'
        'Cells(i, 3).value = "=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), TRUE, **[IF][1]**(***ID is the same, add the cell to the range to
        'capture all Materials for this specific ID# into the first cell for each ID*** , ""))"
        
              
    'If next row doesn't match the previous, assign another color
         If Cells(i, 1).value <> Cells(i + 1, 1).value Then


            r = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(128, 255)
            g = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(128, 255)
            b = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(128, 255)
         End If
         
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: You can do this in a Pivot without any code at all - just add ID & Materials to 'Rows' and then format as Tabular. You can pick color formatting here to alternate rows as well.

Comment: You could also achieve the same output with formulas= `TEXTJOIN(FILTER())`

Comment: As @udearboy said.  `=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,FILTER(B$2:B$14,A$2:A$14=A2))` will do it.  I'd also suggest using `=UNIQUE(A2:A14)` to get a unique list of ID's and using that within the filter `,A$2:A$14=<unique list of ID's>`